# Handsontable not showing table with dynamic columns

Tags: handsontable

I'm using the following code to show my table:

```
<hot-table
        settings="{colHeaders: colHeaders, contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row'], afterChange: afterChange,  stretchH: 'all' }" rowHeaders="false"
        datarows="budgetaanvraag.interne_kosten" columns="columns.interne_kosten" class="col s12">
</hot-table>
```

and with the following colums:

```
$scope.calcBedrag = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    var hoeveelheid = instance.getDataAtRowProp(row, 'hoeveelheid');
    var eenheidsprijs = instance.getDataAtRowProp(row, 'eenheidsprijs');

    td.innerHTML = hoeveelheid * eenheidsprijs;
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
};

$scope.columns = {};
$scope.columns.interne_kosten = [
    {
        data: 'naam',
        title: "<b>Interne kosten</b>",
        renderer: 'html',
        width: 100
    },
    {
        data: 'hoeveelheid',
        title: "Hoeveelheid",
        type: 'numeric',
        width: 50
    }, {
        data: 'eenheid',
        title: "Eenheid",
        type: 'numeric',
        width: 100
    }, {
        data: 'eenheidsprijs',
        title: "Eenheidsprijs",
        type: 'numeric',
        width: 50,
        format: '0,0.00'
    },
    {
        data: 'bedrag',
        title: "Bedrag",
        type: 'numeric',
        width: 50,
        format: '0,0.00',
        renderer: $scope.calcBedrag,
        readonly: true
    }
];
```

but this always remains showing an empty table
when enabling the row headers it just shows:
[image]

this is the data used here: https://gist.github.com/cskiwi/a57de031f752df1182be

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out what was causing the error:

if you use the $scope.columns it messes up the thing :)